# How come variables are initialized to their default values even if we have a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, default, default-constructor

i have a question regarding default constructors in java.
as much as i have read about constructors in java, a default constructor initializes all instance variables to their default values. but what if we define a constructor for a class, then how come variables are initialized to their default values if we want them to ?

suppose i have 2 files 
a.java

```
public class a
{
    int x;

    public a(int z)
    {
        if(z > 0)
        {
            x = z;
        }
    }

    public  void get()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

and b.java

```
public class b
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        a obj = new a(-4);

        obj.get();
    }
}
```

now here condition (z>0) fails, so x is initialized to zero. but what exactly does this as their is no default constructor in class a.

Comment: You never call the default constructor of `a` here...

Comment: Class `a` doesn't have a default constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default **by the compiler**. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

That means that the compiler will do that for you when you build the program.

Comment: @juergen d - doesn't the default constructor initializes the fields to their default values. if not then what is it's purpose in java ?

Comment: No the default constructors' purpose is not to initialize variables with their default value. That happens automatically. You should google about the use of default constructors. it can be used for may cases.

Answer (score 2):

In your `a` class (renamed `A` below to follow conventions) as you have written it, *there is no default constructor*. A default constructor for a class is a constructor which is `public` and has no arguments.

With the code you have written, this will fail:

```
A a = new A();
```

As soon as you declare another constructor in a class, there is no default constructor anymore.

As to instance variables, if you do not initialize them explicitly, they are set to default values. That is:

```
public class A
{
    private int x;

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

if you do:

```
final A a = new A();
System.out.println(a.getX());
```

this will print out `0`. The class above is exactly equivalent to:

```
public class A
{
    private int x /* = 0 -- default value for uninitialized int instance variables */;

    // redundant
    public A()
    {
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable in java, it's by default initialized as it's default value.
For the primitive types is that 0 (or it's equivalent), for Objects is that `null`

So in your example has `x` initialy the value 0 and you never overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

In java if we dont define any constructor, it takes its self a default constructor which will have default values.while we creating object we intialize values to the constructor.

```
public class Car{
  int numOfWheels;

public Car(int numOfWheels){                     //created constructor//

    this.numOfWheels=numOfwheels;
    }
    }
    public static void main(string[]args){

Car skoda = new Car(4);  
}                           *//initialized value to the object using constructor in  parenthesis//*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class a
{
    int x;

    public a(int z)
    {
    //as we know that every class base class is Object class this constructor first statement is super(); means compiler automatically add this statement that call object class default constructor and initialize default values
        if(z > 0)
        {
            x = z;
        }
    }

    public  void get()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class a

{

int x;

public a(int z)

{

/*As we know that every class base class is Object.....

compiler automatically add super(); that call Object class default constructor

that initialize the value of instance variable */

if(z > 0)

{

x = z;

}

}

public  void get()

{

System.out.println(x);

}

} 
public class b

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{

    a obj = new a(-4);


    obj.get();

}
```

}

//other example is below

/*class A

{

public A()

{

System.out.println("Arjun Singh Rawat and Ashish Chinaliya");

}

}

class B extends A

{

public B()

{

//compiler automatically add super();

}

}

class calling

{

public static void main(String arg[])

{

B bb=new B();

}

}*/

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {
    static int a;
    Demo(int b )
{
System.out.println(" Constructor"); 
}
 public static int  func()
 {
     System.out.println(a);
     return 1;
 }
 public static void main( String args[])
 {

     new Demo(func());
 }
}

Output
0
Constructor
```

It's not the default constructor that initializes our fields to their default values ,
In this program,  the static field a is being initialized to 0 even though there is no default constructor 
added by the compiler. Also it's being initialized to 0 before a constructor being called .